# vue-cli not transpiling code to es5 or commonjs when using the target wc build option

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, babeljs, vue-cli-3

I'm trying to build a component using:

`vue-cli-service build --target wc --name my-component ./src/App.vue`

The outputted build js still has `const` and arrow functions. How can I have it transpile to commonjs for example?

I've tried using various presets in the babel config but the build result is still the same.

There is a `babel.config.js` file in project root (generated from vue-cli)

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
  '@vue/app'
  ]
}
```

No errors, the build is occurring but it is not transpiling. It's almost as if the babel config is bypassed when building with target wc

Answer (score 1):

> A default Vue CLI project uses [@vue/babel-preset-app](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/tree/dev/packages/%40vue/babel-preset-app), which uses
>   `@babel/preset-env` and the `browserslist` config to determine the
>   Polyfills needed for your project.
>
> By default, it passes `useBuiltIns: 'usage'` to `@babel/preset-env` which
>   automatically detects the polyfills needed based on the language
>   features used in your source code. This ensures only the minimum
>   amount of polyfills are included in your final bundle. However, this
>   also means **if one of your dependencies has specific requirements on
>   polyfills, by default Babel won't be able to detect it**.
>
> When using Vue CLI to build a [library or Web Components](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/build-targets.html), it is
>   recommended to pass `useBuiltIns: false` to `@vue/babel-preset-app` to
>   disable automatic polyfill injection. This ensures you don't include
>   unnecessary polyfills in your code, as it should be the responsibility
>   of the consuming app to include polyfills.

To build for `CommonJS` use target `--library`:

`vue-cli-service build --target lib --name myLib [entry]`

[Build Targets](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/build-targets.html#library)